# How can I send a keystroke to a hidden window?

Tags: c#

I create a hidden window process for CMD.EXE like so:

```
        //  Create the process start window.
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", null);

        //  Set the options.
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processStartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        //  Specify redirection.
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        //  Create the process.
        currentProcess = new Process();
```

I then handle all input/output myself through redirected streams. However, I want 'tab' to show the auto-completion data. I have tried sending '\t' to the input stream - no joy. If the window is made visible I have the window handle in the process structure and can set it to the foreground and use 'SendKeys'. This is not acceptable though, as I need the window to be invisible.

So does anyone know how to send a keystroke to a process ID?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a project on code project that may do what you need. Its a tutorial on how to send keys to another application. This does need to be an active window.

I know your window needs to be invisible, would an option just to move it outside of the viewable area of the screen? so it can still be visible, but just not in the viewable area.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18366/Sending-Keystrokes-to-another-Application-in-C

Additionally, Can you just start a process directly rather than calling cmd.exe.

eg, call ipconfig.exe rather than cmd.exe and sending ipconfig.exe keystrokes.

Comment: Unfortunately, having an active window isn't possible in this case - I could live with having a hidden window, but process start info doesn't seem to respect the WindowStyle.Hidden enumeration, unless 'use shell execute' is on, which I have to have off!
I can indeed start ipconfig.exe directly, however I have the same issue - I still want to be able to send special characters to the process, whatever it is :S